-XX:StartFlightRecording start recording 1 and 2, why two recordings, what's the difference?
-XX:StartFlightRecording start recording 1 and 2, why two recordings, what's the difference?
By default is 250 MB, what if 250 MB is reached? Auto dump or cover old with new?
$jcmd 247628 JFR.check
247628:
Recording 1: name=1 maxsize=250.0MB (running)

Recording 2: name=2 maxsize=250.0MB (running)


This question is similar to: How to limit disk space usage for JFR recording dumps (in a Docker container)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

-XX:StartFlightRecording only starts one recording, but if it's specified twice, two recordings begin. It's also possible to start another recording using jcmd.
When 250 MB is reached, the oldest 10-15 MB are removed and filled with new data.
